# How does 出てます here translate?

Tags: verbs

Came across this dialogue while reading Japanese writings online.

Boy 1: オタクにじみ出てますよ

Boy 2: 違うっつってんだろ

My Japanese beginner skills would translate it as "Your otaku-ness is bleeding out." But I'm sure that's not exactly right.

Also, I see a lot of ってん in casual dialogues like this. I'm not sure what that exactly means.

Comment: 「にじみ出る」（滲み出る）を調べてみたら・・・

Comment: For っつってん maybe this helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/what-does-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ae-mean/1253#1253

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your understanding of the first sentence is okay. It means something along the lines of "I can smell your otaku-ness", "You are not hiding your otaku trait".

For the second sentence, it's a result of several contractions.

- 違うと言っているだろ(う)
  Come on, I'm saying it's wrong (I'm not an otaku)!
- 違うと言ってるだろ ([ている to てる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010))
- 違うと言ってんだろ ([る(ん)だ to んだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53669/5010))
- 違うって言ってんだろ (って is a casual version of quotative-と)
- 違うっつってんだろ ([って言っ to っつっ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1252/5010))