# What does つった mean?

Tags: words, conjugations

While I was doing Anki I found つった and I don't know what this means, is it つって but past tense? Here is the full sentence.

> 俺もよくついてる　知ってるものを 知らないっつったって

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/what-does-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ae-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, つった is the past-form of (っ)つう or (っ)つー, which is a slangy contraction of と言う or って言う. つう doesn't fully conjugate like a regular godan verb (we do not say ついます, つえば, つわない, etc.), but it does have the te-form and the ta-form:

- つう = と言う
- つって = と言って

  - つってる = と言ってる = と言っている
  - つっとく = と言っとく = と言っておく
  - つっちゃう = と言っちゃう = と言ってしまう
  - つったる = と言ったる = と言ってやる
- つった = と言った

  - つったり = と言ったり
  - つったら = と言ったら

Some non-straightforward examples:

- 見たっつったの？ = 見たって言ったの？ = D'you say you saw it?
- 馬鹿っつったった = 馬鹿と言ってやった = I said to him (he was) an idiot.
- 何つうか = 何というか = well; um; what can I say
- つうことは = ということは = that is to say; which means
- つうか = というか = っていうか = or rather; or perhaps; wait
- つっても = と言っても = that said; but
- なんつって! = just kidding! (probably from などと言っちゃって)

Related:

- [What does っつの mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1252/5010)
- [How does 出てます here translate?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66194/5010)