# What does っぽいっつったけど mean?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension, quotes

> 俺に必死かよ！
> 淡泊っぽいっつったけど
> 意外とおこちゃまみてーなとこもあんだなぁ
> お前よ

The character is a delinquent so he tends to slur some words together. The dialog is ALL spoken by a single person. This is the character's response after his lover doesn't answer him to the question "Were you jealous?" so he says this.

My reading is akin:

> 俺に必死かよ！

You are really desperate about me!

> 意外とおこちゃまみてーなとこもあんだなぁ

You also have some childish like parts

> お前よ

You! (it sound weird in English but I'm being literal)

However 淡泊っぽいっつったけど is the confusing part. I understand it's akin to 「～って言って」 but I'm struggling to connect it with "淡泊っぽい".

Comment: Related, perhaps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/77691/9831

Answer (score 1):

For つった, see: [What does つった mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77674/5010) and [What does っつの mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1252/5010)

淡泊 in this context is "emotionless", "not enthusiastic", "uninterested", "stoic", etc.

> 淡泊っぽいっつったけど
> ≈ 「淡泊っぽい」って言ったけど
>
> I said (earlier) that you looked emotionless somehow, but...