# Understanding 「いん」in なんでお前がここにいんのよ

Tags: grammar, contractions

I'm following Tae Kim's grammar guide, and am confused about this sentence: なんでお前がここにいんのよ, which is translated as 'why are you here?'. I'm pretty sure that いん is some form of いる but I can't figure out what.

Comment: [~るの = ~んの](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/07/contractions.html#runo-to-nno)

Comment: Related posts are too many to do an exhaustive list, but I hope these ones help: 1. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54000  2. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958  3. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53668/