# What is んの short for in 「なんで鍵なんか閉めてんの？」

Tags: contractions

I'm familar how ん can help form contractions like:

- んです ↦ のです
- なんです ↦ なのです

but I recently came across んの:

> あれ お兄ちゃん
> なんで鍵なんか閉めて**んの**？

What is this short for? My best guess is that ん is short for いる and の is short for のですか. Is this the case?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61958/why-is-the-%e3%81%a6-form-being-used-before-%e3%82%93 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53668/what-is-the-formal-expression-of-%e4%bd%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0